# How can I draw with canvas over an xml background?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on a simple project for my studies and I’m stuck with this problem.
I'm building Snakes And Ladders app and I’m trying to make my player (PNG image) to move around the board an animate.
I want the animation to happen over the game’s board background which I defined in an xml file and I just can’t do it.
The program that I will attach is not working, I have no idea why. In addition I need to add the part that takes the xml background in consideration, that part is missing and I will greatly appreciate if someone can help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advanced.

The board xml file(game.xml):

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/easymap"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/whitePlayer"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blackPlayer"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/black"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btRoll"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cubePic"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                    android:text="Roll"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cubePic"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cube" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTurn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cubePic"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btRoll"
                    android:text="Your turn!"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        The java class:

        package com.example.snakesnladders;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.graphics.Canvas;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
        import android.view.SurfaceView;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class GFX_Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            TextView whitePlayer, blackPlayer;
            Button roll;
            TextView cube, map1, map2, map3, label;
            boolean yourTurn = true;
            MyBringBack ourView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                ourView = new MyBringBack(this);
                setContentView(ourView);
                init();
            }

            private void init() {
                cube = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cubePic);
                roll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRoll);
                label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTurn);
                roll.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

            }

            class MyBringBack extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

                SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
                Thread ourThread = null;
                Bitmap backGround, playerB, playerW;
                boolean isRunning = true;

                public MyBringBack(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                    playerW = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.id.whitePlayer);
                    ourHolder = getHolder();
                    ourThread = new Thread(this);
                    ourThread.start();

                }

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (isRunning) {
                        if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                            continue;
                        Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                        canvas.drawBitmap(playerW, 0, 0, null);
                        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

The changed inner class:( I've extended View an override the onDraw method from the Viev class, and it still not working) 
In addition I wanted to draw on my existing xml layout that i created in the game.xml file.

```
    class MyBringBack extends View {
        Bitmap playerW;

        public MyBringBack(Context context) {
            super(context);
            playerW = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.id.whitePlayer);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawBitmap(playerW,0,0,null);
        }

    }
```

Comment: To draw with a canvas you need a custom View class and you need to override its onDraw function.

Comment: I have changed my inner class as you said and its still not working. I'll attach the changed inner class so you can take a look at it.  
class MyBringBack extends View {
  Bitmap playerW;

  public MyBringBack(Context context) {
   super(context);
   playerW = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     R.id.whitePlayer);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onDraw(canvas);
   canvas.drawBitmap(playerW,0,0,null);
  }

 }

Comment: Sorry for the mess I'm new here, I've attached the class above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom View as follows. If you're root view is RelativeLayout and you need to draw on it, extend a RelativeLayout

```
public final class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    Bitmap playerW;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
        super(context, atts, style);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(final Context context) {
        playerW = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.id.whitePlayer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(playerW,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Then use it in xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.name.package.MyRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...
    all the stuff here

<your.package.name.package.MyRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In the xml I wrote:<com.example.snakesnladders.package.MyRelativeLayout.... is it ok?

Comment: Well I tried every variation and it’s not working, when I go to the xml file its throwing me a whole bunch of exceptions :java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1083)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1139)
    at com.example.snakesnladders.MyRelativeLayout.onDraw(MyRelativeLayout.java:36)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
etc.

Comment: In a layout editor? Then in your onDraw method, add after super.onDraw(); if (isInEditMode()) return;